# Determining a left & right side of an Isosceles triangle

Tags: algorithm, opencv, math, trigonometry, android

So I have an image with 3 dots on it.

[image]

This is the correct orientation of the image but it can be at any degree of rotation. My goal is to identify the dots for ease we'll call them Left dot, right dot and bottom dot.

Now getting the bottom dot is easy as you just take the distances between the 3 dots and which ever dot isn't on the longest line is the bottom one.

So that leaves me with problem of identifying the left and right dot. I feel like I've forgotten some basic trig for figuring this out but my google-foo has failed me at uncovering a formula to determine the left and right side.

Comment: Do you mean left and right absolute, or with reference to the apex (as in, the apex is always "up")?

Comment: Not 100% on what you're asking. The left and right dots are relative to the "correct" (or current) orientation of the image. Tho the above image can appear at any degree of rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2D *cross-product* of two vectors, [image], is a scalar which is positive for when `a` is clockwise rotated with respect to `b`, and vice versa. So in the diagram below:

[image]

The left and right points satisfy  [image] and [image]  respectively.